# Bad request 415

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Getting following error when trying to execute CRM web service.\

**Code**

```
            CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
            token.AuthenticationType = 0; //Use AD authentication
            token.OrganizationName = "Organization";
            CrmService service= new CrmService();
            service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
            service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            service.PreAuthenticate=true;
            WhoAmIRequest whoami = new WhoAmIRequest();
            WhoAmIResponse whoResp = ((WhoAmIResponse)(service.Execute(whoami)));
```

**Config setting:**

```
    <add key="CrmSdk.CrmServiceWsdl" value="http://server/organization/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web"/>
```

**Error:**

System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 415: Cannot process the     message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'..

If I change my config settings like below I'm getting "bad request".

**Config setting:**

```
 <add key="CrmSdk.CrmServiceWsdl" value="http://server/organization/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web"/>
```

**Error:**

> The message with Action
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including
>   security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this setup for the 2007 endpoint, so you'll need to change your value from:

```
value="http://server/organization/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web"
```

to

```
value="http://server/org/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmService.asmx"
```

If you are trying to use 2011, you'll need to use the IOrganizationService.  There are some really nice examples in the SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Here's another example as well http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/